# Identity Server 3 first sign in request pending forever until page refreshed

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I am having an issue with IdentityServer 3. First time I try to authenticate towards IdentityServer it keeps loading the page forever, once I refresh the page it loads it immediatelly and I am logged in. On what scenario is this happening?

It looks like Client has sent the request to IdentityServer sso, but the IdentityServer sso does not respond. 
But if we refresh Client and send the request again, IdentityServer sso will respond accordingly.

When I do the request first time after visual studio starts app I see this:
[image: request]

So signin request is pending forever towards sso.

Then when I refresh page (F5) it does normal flow:
[image: requestok]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that ws-fed deadlocks when loading metadata.
Refer to this for problem:
https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/409

And solution is to implement async manager for loading metadata:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Host.Configuration/IdentityServerExtension.cs#L130

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Host.Configuration/Extensions/SyncConfigurationManager.cs